# LinqToSQL read failss with Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net

This statement keeps falling over:

```
    svsCentralDataContext = new SVSCentralDataContext();

                var questions = (from q in _svsCentralDataContext.SVSSurvey_Questions
                                 where q.LevelID == _intSelectedLevelId
                                 orderby q.Sequence
                                 select q);
```

The value of intSelectedLevelId is OK.
I have tested the read in SQL, no problem.
Any ideas why it is failing, or how to solve it?

Comment: _intSelectedLevelId or _svsCentralDataContext is null or empty . did you check it by using break point?

Comment: Is LevelID a nullable column in the table you're selecting from?

Comment: And where is the _svsCentralDataContext object ? and _intSelectedLevelId variable?

Comment: I checked the values using a breakpoint. _intSelectedLevelId has a value of 4, with records in the database to match. _svsCentralDataContext is fine. However, the field LevelID is indeed a nullable column. Could this be the problem?  This read works fine on another page!!!

Comment: The nullable fields question is a red herring. I changed the design of the fields in the SQL to NOT NULL. Still got same error. Also tried removing the orderby clause. Same error.

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo or not so I'm doing this as a comment, but in your code you're initialising the variable "svsCentralDataContext" but in your LINQ query you're using "_svsCentralDataContext" (note the underscore).

Comment: Solved it. For some reason the _svsCentralDataContext was null. The line shown above, the wrong datacontext is used.